# Uncaught TypeError: quotesData[currentQuote] is undefined

Tags: javascript

i try to build a simple javasciprt random quote app but in the very first test of my code i saw this in console :  **Uncaught TypeError: quotesData[currentQuote] is undefined
showquote http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/main.js:31
 http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/main.js:37**

this is js code source :

```
quotesData = [{
    quote: `There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle.`,
    name: 'Albert Einstein '
  },
  {
    quote: `Good friends, good books, and a sleepy conscience: this is the ideal life.`,
    name: 'Mark Twain'
  },
  {
    quote: `Life is what happens to us while we are making other plans.`,
    name: 'Allen Saunders '
  },
  {
    quote: `It's not the load that breaks you down, it's the way you carry it.`,
    name: 'Lou Holt'
  },
  {
    quote: `Try not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.`,
    name: 'Albert Einstein '
  },
]
/* important variables */
const currentQuote = quotesData[0];
const quoteText = document.getElementById('quote');
const quotebtn = document.getElementById('q-btn');
const quotepan = document.getElementById('q-span');

/* this function is for show the quote and author name */
function showquote() {
  quoteText.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].quote;
  quotespan.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].name;

  currentQuote++;
};
/* this function is for change the quote and author name with evrey click */
quotebtn.addEventListener('click', showquote())
```

Comment: `quotebtn.addEventListener('click', showquote())`   <-- wrong should be `quotebtn.addEventListener('click', showquote)`

Comment: K I answered the question but still, I have never heard of an error of the form `... is undefined`. It's more like `Cannot read property ... of undefined`. Where did you get the error message in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

`currentQuote` isn't an array index, it's an element of the array.

You need to set it to `0`, and it can't be `const` if you want to increment it.

```
let currentQuote = 0;
```

Also, the second argument to `addEventListener` should be a reference to a function. You're calling the function immediately instead of saving it as a listener.

```
quotebtn.addEventListener('click', showquote);
```

After you increment `currentQuote`, you need to check if you've reached the end of the array and wrap around. You can do this using the modulus operator.

```
function showquote() {
  quoteText.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].quote;
  quotespan.innerText = quotesData[currentQuote].name;

  currentQuote = (currentQuote + 1) % quotesData.length;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems with your code -

1. Replace `quotebtn.addEventListener('click', showquote())` with `quotebtn.addEventListener('click', showquote)` because otherwise you are passing the return value of showquote to the function.
2. `currentQuote` is an **object** which cannot be passed as an index. You need to set `currentQuote` to `0` so you can increment it.
   This is still not random quotes, but it solves your problems.
3. `currentQuote` is a constant variable - which means you can't increment it because `++` is actually just syntactic sugar for `+= 1` which in itself is syntactic sugar for `currentQuote = currentQuote + 1`. Change it to let.

TIP:
Do not mix ES5 and ES6. Old functions should only be used when access to the `this` keyword is needed. Otherwise, stick to one version for semantic purposes.